# Incorrect component name in App Insights on Azure, using OpenTelemetry

Tags: azure, trace, open-telemetry

I'm using OpenTelemetry to trace my service running on Azure.

Azure Application Map is showing incorrect name for the components sending the trace. It is also sending incorrect `Cloud RoleName` which is probably why this is happening. The `Cloud RoleName` that App Insights is displaying is Function App name and not the Function name.

In my Azure Function (called `FirewallCreate`), I start a trace using following util method:

```
def get_otel_new_tracer(name=__name__):
    # Setup a TracerProvider(). For more details read:
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python#set-the-cloud-role-name-and-the-cloud-role-instance
    trace.set_tracer_provider(
        TracerProvider(
            resource=Resource.create(
                {
                    SERVICE_NAME: name,
                    SERVICE_NAMESPACE: name,
                    # SERVICE_INSTANCE-ID: "my-instance-id"
                }
            )
        )
    )

    # Send messages to Exporter in batches
    span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(
    AzureMonitorTraceExporter.from_connection_string(
        os.environ["TRACE_APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
        )
    )
    trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(span_processor)

    return trace.get_tracer(name)


def firewall_create():
    tracer = get_otel_new_tracer("FirewallCreate")
    with tracer.start_new_span("span-firewall-create") as span:
        # do some stuff
        ...
```

The traces show *another* function name, in the same function app (picture attached).[image]

1. What mistake I could be making?
2. The component has `0 ms` and `0 calls` in it. What does it mean? How to interpret it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks for trying out OpenTelemetry with Application Insights! First of all, are you using the [azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter](https://pypi.org/project/azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter/), and if so, what version are you using? I've also answered your questions inline:

> What mistake I could be making?

What name are you trying to set your component to? The exporter will attempt to set your `cloudRoleName` to `<service_namespace>.<service_name>` by default that you set in your `Resource`. If `<service_namespace>` is not populated, it takes the value of `<service_name>`.

> The component has 0 ms and 0 calls in it. What does it mean? How to interpret it?

Is this the only node in your application map? We need to first find whether this node is created by the exporter or by the functions runtime itself.

Comment: I'm setting the component name to be function name (`FirewallCreate`) in above code. The function app has 6 other functions. In the `Resource`, both the SERVICE_NAME and SERVICE_NAMESPACE are set to function name. In my application there are 2 other components (Azure Functions) and 4 other nodes (two instances of CosmosDB, Service Bus, Blob Storage). _We need to first find whether this node is created by the exporter or by the functions runtime itself_ -> How can I find this?

Comment: If you set <SERVICE_NAME> and <SERVICE_NAMESPACE> to both `FirewallCreate`, your cloudRoleName should appear as `FirewallCreate.FirewallCreate`. Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: Also for testing purposes, could you make the name shorter so we can visually see it in the application map?

Comment: The `cloudRoleName` is not appearing as `FirewallCreate.FirewallCreate`. It is appearing as function-app-name, which is different than function name. As you suggested, I'll rename components shorter and generate an application map. I'll update here in 2 days.

Comment: I figured this out. I have a function app with 6 functions in it. In each one of them, I created a tracer as global variable. Input to the tracer is the respective function name. Traces sent by all the functions had *same* function name, as original post indicated. Once I created *local* tracer object instead of global, it resolved the issue.